# IF ELSE IF error , 1st condition working only

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I am trying change one column value with a link, like if the column value is published it will changed to unpublished and vice versa. But the problem is that only if condition is working not else if.

Here is the link:

```
echo "<td><a href='testi.php?change_status={$testi_id}&status={$testi_status}'>Publish / Unpublish</a></td>";
```

And the php code to change the status:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['change_status'])){
    $the_status =  escape($_GET['status']);
    $the_testi_id = escape($_GET['change_status']);


    if  ($the_status='published'){
    $query = "UPDATE testimonial SET testi_status = 'unpublished' WHERE testi_id = $the_testi_id   ";
    $change_to_sub_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query); }

   else if ($the_status='unpublished'){
        $query = "UPDATE testimonial SET testi_status = 'published' WHERE testi_id = $the_testi_id   ";
        $change_to_sub_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

    }

    header("Location: testi.php");



}  ?>
```

Comment: You're assigning rather that comparing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes sir, silly mistake :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single `=` sets, double `==` checks, triple `===` checks explicitly.

When you do

```
if ($value='foo') {}
```

What it is doing is checking if `$value` was set to `'foo'` which will always evaluate to `true`.

So you want `if ($value == 'foo')` instead.

In what you have written, it will never evaluate the `elseif` because `if` will always be true.

---

For reference, the difference between `==` and `===`

```
//evalates to true
if (1 == true) { ... }

//evaluates to false
if (1 === true) { ... }

//evaluates to true
if (1 === 1) { ... }

//evaluates to true
if (true === true) { ... }
```

Comment: opps and thanks sir :)

Comment: this question has been asked many times and you've explained it the same way as all others. There isn't any added benefit and should have been flagged as such. Closing it was good enough.